# Why Arduino does not suit the to trigger a Spark plug but 555 timer can?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, transformer, 555, spark

To trigger a spark plug and to control it using an Arduino, I tried following [this really well-written guide](http://christian.liljedahl.dk/guides/arduino-spark-plug).

Basically, a MOSFET([IRF540N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf540n.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355e396cb199f) in my case) controls the closing and opening of the primary winding of the ignition coil(which basically is a transformer), while an Arduino triggers the MOSFET.

But this never worked.

The sparks were small and low in repetition; MOSFET was heating up; Arduino's Tx and Rx light kept flickering; etc. etc. It was never as shown in the blog linked above.

But once the Arduino was replaced by the 555 timers, all was well. Except the mild heating of MOSFET, everything was sorted out.

What could be modified with the Arduino circuit to get it up and running as shown in the guide linked above? Why is Arduino suffering which 555 timer is able to handle?

Comment: Don't know the numbers so I could be wrong, but this sounds like the arduino can't charge that FET's gate as fast as the 555 timer, and as a result you get a less sharp rise and because of it lower spark size.

Comment: Do you mean the MOSFET number? It was IRF560N

Comment: I meant "I don't have the time nor the expertise in this filed to do the math for you, but if I were you this is where I would start looking"

Comment: @JorenVaes will such a sharp rise of (what?) make the Tx and Rx lights to blink?

Comment: With the rise we mean the speed at which the signals go from one state to another - in this case the speed at which the MOSFET can turn on. This is influenced by how fast the (in your case) arduino can drive the MOSFET input. This input is a capacitor that needs to be charged and if the arduino can't do it fast enough, it takes a long time for the MOSFET to turn on and you do not get the fast speed you want.

Comment: Sounds about right. IRF560N has Vgs 2.0-4.0V and input capacitance 2nF. I would add MOSFET driver chip. As for Tx/Rx flickering the most probable culprit is bad decoupling. I cannot imagine more noise generating device than a spark plug.

Comment: @Maple - I am just a hobbyist. Can you please help in explaining what is a bad decoupling? Thanks, I will look into MOSFET drivers!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_capacitor You have those on your Arduino already, but they were never intended to protect from _really_ bad noise.

Comment: @Maple I think you just looked at the IRF540N data sheet. I don't think there is an IRF560N device but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Ooops... you are right, that's what I was looking at

Comment: @Maple I will look into it. BTW, IRF560N is a MOSFET-https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf540n.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355e396cb199f

Comment: @karthikeyan please link to the data sheet for the IRF560N MOSFET you said you used. Also, why didn't you use the one specified in the "really well written guide".

Comment: @karthikeyan BTW, find "Radio Frequency interference" in the guide you were using. It has warnings about exactly this kind of problems and even suggests a solution. If you follow some guide it is always beneficial to be thorough. Also, if your Arduino is 3.3V then make sure you power fet driver (or transistor) with at least 5V

Comment: @karthikeyan No, that's an IRF540N MOSFET. -1 for wasting time and my patience.

Comment: @Andyaka - I linked the Datasheet in the comment . I will edit the question and add the same. In my country, I couldn't get the same MOSFET mentioned.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry that you can't handle a mistake. It was a typo. And I happily take the -1

Answer (score 1):

The original link shows an NDP5060L was used, you made a substitution without understanding the required ratings. The web site also shows a (now 404) link to driving a FET, so clearly there is more to the schematic than shown.

The original circuit was a very marginal design, since a 60V FET (the NDP5060) was used in an application that requires perhaps 300V VDS capability. I would imagine it would be likely to fail often.

Your selection of an IRF540 is just as likely to fail since it is only 100V rating. It's also very difficult to drive high capacitance gates directly from an Arduino (or any other MCU).

To drive a power FET and get low turn off times (the turn on time is almost irrelevant in this application) you need to be able to discharge the FET gate very rapidly.

You could drive the gate with an H-Bridge driver such as the [SN754410](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/datasheets/SN754410.pdf) or the [L293](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293d.pdf) (you only need one channel) and these would give adequate results (though you should have a series resistor to the gate being driven).

A more modern device with excellent performance is the ON Semi [FAN3268](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FAN3268T_F085-D.PDF) this provides FET outputs (no series resistor required) rather than BJT and works for 3 -5V MCU direct drive (you would only use the low side driver).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQzBaI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The original article used a [b]logic level[/b] Mosfet that uses a gate voltage of 4.5V to fully turn on but you used a normal IRF Mosfet that needs a gate voltage of 10V that is not produced by the Arduino. You should have used a [b]logic level[/b] high voltage Mosfet.
An IRL540 (see the "L"?) is logic level but it is not a high voltage type.